# OpenLayers getFeatureInfo popup generates this.size is null

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to create OpenLayers with popup feature info. I got the code from OpenLayers examples and only modified url to my local geoserver. The map is displaying, when i click on a feature the request is sent but the response is empty and firebug shows error "this.size is null". When i run the request url separately feature info is generated.
Here is the code:

```
var map, info;

function load() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(20.163,53.228,20.208,53.257)
        //maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(143.834,-43.648,148.479,-39.573)
        //maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(19,90,19,90)
    });

    var punkty_zdjecia = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Punkty Zdjecia",
        "http://localhost:6060/geoserver/wms", 
        {'layers': 'cite:ulice2', transparent: false, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: true}
    );

    map.addLayers([punkty_zdjecia]); 

    info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://localhost:6060/geoserver/wms', 
        title: 'Test url',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

I am using OpenLayers 2.11 and Firefox browser

Comment: Data in geoserver is in polish crs EPSG:2178, when i specified OpenLayers.Bounds() with coordinates in this crs, map was empty. I had to provide lat long coords in bounds to show the map - maybe this is causing error?

Comment: Is your application running http://localhost:6060/ ?

Comment: My geoserver is running localhost:6060, openlayers is placed in my http server at localhost:80. Map is displaying correctly - getFeatureInfo with Popup is not working

Comment: Ok, then the problem is that you are making cross domain request from localhost:80 to localhost:6060 which is not allowed by browser. You need a proxy

Comment: Great! That was the problem. After deploying openlayers to localhost:6060 everything worked. Still got problems configuring proxy.cgi from the examples on my http server (Windows). Anyway problem solved. Thanks.